# VB.Net Has multiple definitions with identical signatures

Tags: vb.net

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Major 2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  COM Reference 'WMPLib' is the interop assembly for ActiveX control 'AxWMPLib' but was marked to be linked by the compiler with the /link flag. This COM reference will be treated as a reference and will not be linked.
1>C:\Users\James\Google Drive\School\SDD\VB Work\VB Task 2\Major 2\Major 2\My Project\Application1.Designer.vb(25,20): error BC30269: 'Public Sub New()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.
1>C:\Users\James\Google Drive\School\SDD\VB Work\VB Task 2\Major 2\Major 2\My Project\Application1.Designer.vb(34,33): error BC30269: 'Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What Have I done wrong?

```
Namespace My

    'NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.  To make changes,
    ' or if you encounter build errors in this file, go to the Project Designer
    ' (go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in
    ' Solution Explorer), and make changes on the Application tab.
    '
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = false
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = true
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = true
            Me.ShutDownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterAllFormsClose
        End Sub

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.Major_2.Main_Screen
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This is the double up in the code but i don't know what  too change in the Application Designer.

Comment: **What Have I done wrong?** - You haven't posted the codes referring to the error, that's what you have done wrong. No one can help you just by looking at this

Comment: Sorry fixed, I was a bit confused.

Comment: Still on the wrong side mate! Note what the comment states in the second line `NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.` You might have wrote **your own code** for `Public Sub New()` & `Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()`. That's what raising the issue!

Comment: I have not touched this code, Just double clicked the error. It doubled up on the code itself.

Comment: It will probably be quicker to abandon any further development of that project and start a new one than to try and fix it. You can still copy-and-paste the code you wrote into the new project - then if you try compiling it after each bit that you paste in you will be able to tell if VS messed up or if it was confused by your code.

Comment: Press `Ctrl-Shift-F` and search the entire solution for `Public Sub New()` and `OnCreateMainForm` and see if you can find the duplicates that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out google drive duplicated one of my files so there was two and it was opening both

Answer (score 3):

**Cause of error:**

It seems that VS sometimes duplicating the `Application.Designer.vb` files under the `Application.myapp` section, (or it could be caused by the human error like the author did.) and for the correctly working project it should only have **ONE** `Application.Designer.vb` file.

**Solution:**

To fix this error, you need to delete the extra `Application.Designer.vb` files. The result should be looks like the picture given in below.

[image]